# Flask render html only when post api gets data

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to build an app that when the api comes with different colors the html will be rendered automaticaly. I have this but does nothing :(

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
import time
import os, sys
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
   return render_template('index.html')                                                                                                              

@app.route("/api/green", methods=['POST'])
def green():
   data = request.get_json()
   templateData = {
     'fname' : data["green"]
     }
   return render_template('green.html', **templateData) 

@app.route("/api/red", methods=['POST'])
def red():
   data = request.get_json()
   templateData = {
     'fname' : data["red"]
     }
   return render_template('red.html', **templateData)

@app.route("/api/orange", methods=['POST'])
def orange():
   data = request.get_json()
   templateData = {
     'fname' : data["orange"]
     }
   return render_template('orange.html', **templateData)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css/">
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" /> -->
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="content container">
        {% block main %}{% endblock main %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the other html files

```
//green.html
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block main %}
<h2>{{ green }}</h2>
{% endblock main %}

//red.html
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block main %}
<h2>{{ red }}</h2>
{% endblock main %}

//orange.html
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block main %}
<h2>{{ orange }}</h2>
{% endblock main %}
```

The best would be to create whole new template html files for all the cases and then after a certain time to redirect to index.

Answer (score 0):

In the templates `red.html, orange.html & green.html`, the variable name used are `red, orange & green` respectively. But you are sending no such variable to these HTML files.
Try something like this:

```
@app.route("/api/green", methods=['POST'])
def green():
   data = request.get_json()
   templateData = {
     'fname' : data["green"]
     }
   return render_template('green.html', green=templateData) #Change in this line
```

Do this for all other routes also.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

I made ** templateData so I grab all the data and pass to html everything!

edit:
But, the problem is that I'm getting this
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

with this script

    @app.route("/")
@app.route("/api/green", methods=['POST'])
def green():
      data = request.get_json()
      templateData = {
         'fname' : data["fname"]
         }
      return render_template('index.html', **templateData)

I think it is because when I refresh the data is not there, and when I call the api green nothing happens!!!